# jquery autocomplete reload the data

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a list of data, say ["foo", "bar"] for the autocomplete, once the user choose one of them via clicking or entering Enter, say "foo", then the next time the user inputs, i want "foo" disappear from the dropdown, is there any way of achieving this? I see nothing about this from the autodomplete doc

Here's what I've done, [autocomplete and remove the chosen one](https://gist.github.com/1209266)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the source option, e.g.

var newSource = [...];
jQuery("#id").autocomplete("option", newSource);

Comment: you mean in the callback function? that will incur an infinite loop and end up with stack too deep error

Answer (score 0):

If your list has not too many items (I mean < 50), you can manage it via a JS array and suppress the chosen item from the array using the splice() method.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i can not tell exactly how many items there are in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each( val, function(k, v){
       if($.inArray(v,selectedCities)!=-1){
        val.splice(k, 1); // remove if already selected
        return;
    }
});
```